# How to place a control in windows forms in a gridview with relative position rather than a fixed position

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to place a time picker control on the cell of my grid view, using the current cell location as in the below code.

```
dtpTerminationDate.Location = gvEmployeeTermination
   .GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False).Location
```

`dtpTerminationDate` is my `TimePicker` object.

This is getting placed fine initially, but the issue is my grid view has a horizontal scroll. So, when I scroll, the UI is distorted.

Before scrolling,

[image: Before scrolling]

After scrolling,

[image: After scrolling]

Can someone please help me to position the `TimePicker` even when I scroll the gridview.

Comment: formatted code for readability, inlined images

Comment: You need to create a custom `DataGridViewColumn`. You should not position controls over cells. Here you can find it: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells#code-snippet-1). It describes how to create a date picker column.